# Async call alternative in onBeforeRequest listener

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

For my Chrome extension, I would like to have blocking requests functional. I have a big list of domains(~10000) I was thinking about using IndexedDb for storing the list of domains, but as I understand now - it's impossible to make an asynchronous call and return the result in request handler.
My initial plan was:

```
function reqHandler(data) {
  // async IndexedDb call here 
  // and return { cancel: true } or { cancel: false } depends on result
}
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  reqHandler,
  { urls: ['<all_urls>'] },
  ['blocking']);
```

It looks like it's impossible?
What is the best way to handle my case? How to deal with the list of domains of this size? I think it's too big for having it in the memory as an object.
Hopefully, you will show me the way to go with the issue. Thank you

Comment: Have you tried keeping it in memory?

Comment: Supply the domain array in `urls` so that Chrome handles the filtering which is the reason this feature exists.

Comment: Did you ever find a reasonable solution for this?

Comment: @Anthony Eventually we haven't used IndexedDb - so no. For our particular case, local storage was good enough to store the list and to get it in reqHandler

Comment: @AlexEfremov I couldn't find a way to make an async call within the function while still having the redirect work, luckily I was able to create a workaround for what I was trying to achieve but the question still remains as to whether it's even possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Create JS file, like BlockUrl.js and put the array variable, where you will store the urls, like:

```
UrlBlck = [
    "*://*.something.com/*",
];
```

In another JS file like Code.js, put this code:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) {
        return {cancel: true}
    },
    {urls: UrlBlck},
    ["blocking"]
)
```

In "manifest.json" put this, after header (name, author, version and that stuff):

```
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["BlockUrl.js", "Code.js"]
  },
```

"content_scripts" section should look like this:
(you must have at least one JS file because of "rules", if you don't have some other JS file, create one empty file)

```
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["*://*/*"],
    "js": ["Empty.js"]
  }],
```

At the end of manifest:

```
  "permissions": ["webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "<all_urls>"]
```

Now you can try...