# How do you get the URL with activeTab inside of a webRequest callback fn?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v2

### Objective

I'm trying to get the active tab's url when the user goes to a new website. The chrome web store has suggested that I remove the `tabs` permission and use `activeTab` instead. I don't have a content script and only need the active URL.

### Current Code

I currently get the active tab and save it to a global variable with the tabs permission:

```js
let ACTIVE_URL = '';

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener((_activeInfo)=> {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, (tabs) => {
        ACTIVE_URL = tabs[0].url || tabs[0].pendingUrl || ACTIVE_URL;
    });
});

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((_tabID, _changeInfo, tab) => {
    ACTIVE_URL = tab.url || ACTIVE_URL;
});
```

### Docs say it's possible?

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63151370/get-url-from-chrome-tabs-onupdated-with-activetab-permission), and woxxom's comments seem to indicate that it's not possible. But according to [activeTab documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/manifest/activeTab/), activeTab allows you to

> Intercept network requests in the tab to the tab's main frame origin using the webRequest API. The extension temporarily gets host permissions for the tab's main frame origin.

So it seems like this is possible (in place of placeholder `chrome.getActiveUrl();`).

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    (webRequest) => {
        const activeURL = ACTIVE_URL // chrome.getActiveUrl();
        if (activeURL === url.im.looking.for) {
            return {cancel: true};
        }
        return {cancel: false};    
    },
    {
        urls: ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        types: ['main_frame']
    },
    ['blocking']
);
```

### Async alternatives

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43141281/async-call-alternative-in-onbeforerequest-listener) says it's not possible to use an async function inside of the onBeforeRequest listener.

### Question

How do you get the URL with activeTab inside of a webRequest callback fn?

Comment: The `activeTab` permission grants access to the document in the active tab at the moment when the user invoked the extension via a click or hotkey. There's no user interaction in this scenario at all so it won't help here.

Comment: Cheers. So it sounds like the documentation is wrong? It looks like I can post an issue to docs.

Comment: The documentation is correct. You and the reviewer are misunderstanding it.

Comment: Although I agree it could be improved by using HUGE BOLD LETTERS on a bright yellow background for its first paragraph :-) and probably even make it `position:sticky` so it's always on the screen.

Comment: This isn't a human - it's an automated review to reduce the number of permissions. Wouldn't `While the activeTab permission is enabled for a tab, an extension can:... Intercept network requests in the tab to the tab's main frame origin using the webRequest API. The extension temporarily gets host permissions for the tab's main frame origin.` seem to indicate that you can use webRequest and activeTab together?

Comment: In your case it's not `enabled`, see the first paragraph of activeTab's documentation.